# Exception caught for getStockCount Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am getting error while calling procedure from Spring application

```
ERROR | 2024-02-28 12:43:23 | [http-/127.0.0.1:8881-1] impl.ProductDAOImpl (ProductDAOImpl.java:702)
- Exception caught for getStockCount Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter 
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter   
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)  
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)   
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)   
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)   
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkIsOutputParam(CallableStatement.java:643)   
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1714)    
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1722)
```

I am calling same procedure from MySQL database it is working fine, without any exception or failure.

there is no specific reason, I have tried to call different procedure within same code block and it was working but this procedure throwing error.

Below function throwing error at this line.

```
callStmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

```
public Integer getStockCount(String partNumber){
    Integer stockCount = null;    
    String query = "{CALL calculate_stock_count(?, ?)}";        
    Connection connection = null;
    CallableStatement callStmt = null;
    
    try {
        connection = this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();        
        callStmt = connection.prepareCall(query);        
        callStmt.setString(1, partNumber);        
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);        
        callStmt.execute();        
        stockCount = callStmt.getInt(2);        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Exception caught for getStockCount " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(callStmt != null){
                callStmt.close();
            }
            if(connection != null){
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Exception caught in getStockCount while closing the connection" + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally{
            if(connection != null){
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.error("Exception caught in getStockCount while closing the connection" + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return stockCount;
}
```

Comment: my guess, you are trying to get the second returned value, while only one value is returned

Comment: This is the Procedure in which first is IN parameter and 2nd out. It is working in database.

CALL calculate_stock_count(10000357, @out_value);
SELECT @out_value;

Comment: according to the documentation, the parameter index is invalid. can't say much more than that

Comment: You had a link to a picture called "database call" but no picture. Please add the code of the procedure too. If you're sure about the parameters, could it be that you have different version of the procedure with the same name in a different place and you're calling that one instead?